# Using JSON data to create treemap using google charts or d3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js, google-visualization

A part of my JSON data is as follows.

`[
{
    "App": "app1",
    "count": 8,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app2",
    "count": 7,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app3",
    "count": 12,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app4",
    "count": 2,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app5",
    "count": 25,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app6",
    "count": 49,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app7",
    "count": 5,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  },
  {
    "App": "app8",
    "count": 189,
    "country": "FR",
    "period": "2018"
  }
]`
.
I want to draw a treemap for this JSON data which would look like this :

[image]

The treemap is drawn based on the count value for the different apps. Country and period can be ignored.

I found this documentation [Populating Data](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example) But the problem is the DataTable has to be in a particular format which is not quite similar to my DataTable. Please suggest how can I do it using d3.js or Google charts?

Comment: you can do something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799414/5090771), where the question is the same example you provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the way.
There are two possible ways to do this:

- Convert your JSON data to an array of array and then follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap).
- Using Angular-google-chart. For this, you have to convert your data to the DataTable format as described [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam). Afterward, you can follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example).

I did it using the first method.

```
// treemap.js  

var objarr = [
  {
"App": "app1",
"count": 8,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  },
  {
"App": "app2",
"count": 7,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  },
  {
"App": "app3",
"count": 12,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  },
{
"App": "app4",
"count": 2,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
},
  {
"App": "app5",
"count": 25,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  },
  {
"App": "app6",
"count": 49,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  },
  {
"App": "app7",
"count": 5,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  },
  {
"App": "app8",
"count": 189,
"country": "FR",
"period": "2018"
  }
]
var arrArr = [['app','parent', 'count'],['app', null, 0]]

var n = objarr.length;

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++){
  arrArr[i+2] = [objarr[i].App, 'app', objarr[i].count]
}
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrArr);

    tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    tree.draw(data, {
      minColor: '#f00',
      midColor: '#ddd',
      maxColor: '#0d0',
      headerHeight: 15,
      fontColor: 'black',
      showScale: true
    });

  }
```

And use this script in your index.html.

```
// index.html  
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="try.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```